# Can i apply integral property on this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$\int\int_{R}|xy|dydx$

Can i apply this integral property(given below) in the above mentioned  integral?

$\int\int_R |f(x,y)|dydx=2\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} f(x,y)dydx$ ?

Comment: I think you mean $4\cdot $, as you are turning a plane into four quadrants.

Comment: Ohh yes thank you. My answer was coming 3/16 and its 3/8 silly me.

Comment: @ThePhenotype you can write it as answer if u want thumbs up and a tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's convergent, then yes (with $4\cdot $).

This holds for the integral on a $2n\times 2n$-square with center $0$. Now letting $n\to\infty$ they both diverge (but consistently divergent as equals, so they are "equal".)